# WooCommerce - excelling eCommerce - How do I display the product weight via php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I display the product weight via php? I want to modify the template and display the product weight next to the price within wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/price.php

http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't change the core plugins for WooCommerce if you can help it.

You can use:

```
.insertBefore
```

jQuery variable to adjust were that metadata loads.